# Efficient representing sub-graphs (data structure) in Python

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, graph

What is the efficient way of keeping and comparing generated sub-graphs from given input graph G in Python?

Some details:

1. Input graph G is a directed, simple graph with number of vertices varying from n=100-10000. Number of edges - it can be assumed that maximum would be 10% of complete graph (usually less) so it gives in that case maximum number of n*(n-1)/10
2. There is an algorithm that can generate from input graph G sub-graphs in number of hundreds/thousands. And for each sub-graph are made some (time consuming) computations.
   Pair "subgraph, computation results" must be stored for later use (dynamic programming approach - if given sub-graph were already processed we want to re-use its results).
3. Because of point (2.) it would be really nice to store sub-graph/results pairs in kind of dictionary where sub-graph is a key. How it can be done efficiently? Some ideas of efficient calculation of sub-graph hash value maybe?
4. Let's assume that memory is not a problem and I can find machine with enough memory to keep a data - so let's focus only on speed.

Of course If there are already nice to use data-structures that might be helpful in this problem (like sparse matrices from scipy) they are very welcome.

I just would like to know your opinions about it and maybe some hints regarding approach to this problem.
I know that there are nice graph/network libraries for Python like NetworkX, igraph, graph-tool which have very efficient algorithms to process provided graph. But seems (or I could not find) efficient way to fulfill points (2. 3.)

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is the data format of the graphs already generated by your algorithm. Does it contruct a new graph by adding vertices and edges ? Is it rewritable ? Does it uses a given format (matrix, adjacency list, vertices and nodes sets etc.)

If you have the choice however, because your subgraph have a "low" cardinality and because space is not an issue, I would store subgraphs as arrays of bitmasks (the bitmask part is optional, but it is hashable and makes a compact set). A subgraph representation would be then

- `L` a list of node references in your global graph `G`. It can also be a bitmask to be used as a hash
- `A` an array of bitmask (matrix) where `A[i][j]` is the truth value of the edge `L[i] -> L[j]`

This takes advantage of the infinite size low space requirement of Python integers. The space complexity is O(n*n) but you get efficient traversal and can easily hash your structure.

Comment: Answering your questions. First subgraph is created from input graph G by removing number of vertices and edges. Next sub-graphs are generated from previously generated sub-graphs (always by removing some V/E). It may happen that from given sub-graph will be created many new sub-graphs. And last but not least -> sub-graphs are not changeable. Once they are created there will be no changes in their structure.

Comment: Note that you can easily and efficiently create the "bitmask" representations, as described in this answer, using [numpy.packbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html).